# Micronaut with Kotlin Class having @Singleton annotation not instantiated

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, singleton, code-injection, micronaut

I have an Micronaut application with modules written in both Java and Kotlin.
Java module(Controller logic) has an interface, which is implemented by Kotlin Class with @Singleton annotation specified.

But at runtime the Kotlin implementation class is not getting instantiated and is failing with the below exception.
"Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [] of class. No bean of type [] exists..."

The same works if the implementation class is also written in Java.
Any thoughts?

Here are the sample source files :
Controller - DemoController.java,
Interface - Message.java,
Implementation - MessageImpl (kotlin file)

```
package com.example.controllers;

import com.example.service.Message;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Controller("/hello")
public class DemoController {

    private Message message;
    @Inject
    public DemoController(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Get(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return message.getMessage();
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.service;

public interface Message {

    String getMessage();
}
```

```
package com.example.service

import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class MessageImpl: Message {
    override fun getMessage(): String {
        return "hello"
    }

}
```

Note: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/discussions/5254 has the application jar (demo.zip) and the steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your project is not configured properly. You are using Kotlin but your `build.gradle` file is configured only for Java.
If you create a new [Kotlin application with Launch](https://micronaut.io/launch?javaVersion=JDK_11&lang=KOTLIN&build=GRADLE&test=JUNIT&name=demo&package=com.example&type=DEFAULT&version=2.4.2&activity=preview&showing=/build.gradle) you can have an example of the right build.
The only thing I've changed to make it work is the main class because you are using a Java class instead of a Kotlin one.

This is the full `build.gradle` that works:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.30"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.30"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.30"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.4.2"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```